# Could html5 drag&drop do this? or should I go after DOM?

Tags: html

I made this picture hopefully it's clear. I want to drag this element  and move it to another  and make a copy of it there, I actually don't want it to be dragged. I know how to work with DOM, but I don't know anything about HTML5 so what should I do?

[my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfcJV.jpg)

Comment: Please, post some code, to show that you have at least made an attempt to do it yourself.

Comment: So you want to drag it over, copy it and place the original one on the original position? Also `img` is self closing so `<img/>` instead of `<img></img>`.

Comment: yes, and sorry I wasn't paying attention to the tags, I was trying to simplify the question as much as I could .  and no I haven't made an attempt yet I'm playing with it for now. If I'm gonna go with javascript It's hard work and actually I can do my thing but I don't wanna go there (I'm lazy) That's why I tried to see what could I do with html5 before I go there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want what @putvande asks is correct, you could use jQuery UI to achieve this.

To give you an idea, take a look at this demo: [jQuery Droppable: Shopping Cart Demo](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/#shopping-cart). Drag the Buckit Shirt (Products/T-Shirts) to the Shopping Cart and you will se how it copies the element to another element on the page. You can do the same with and . You can view the source code be selecting the view-source link beneath the demo and there is also a link to the complete API documentation for droppable functionality beneath that.

Comment: wow that's good, and when the elements has dropped can I pick it's name up and do something with it? If you could tell this one thing I pretty much can decide? can I get that dropped element and do something with it?

Comment: Yes you can. Check the API documentation I mentioned, there is a list of events for which you can just specificy a function you want to run when triggered.

Comment: It is very easy to implement. jQuery is one of the first things I did to make pages dynamic. It is very well documented and there are a ton of examples with the source code used to implement it. For example they use the drop event trigger to achieve the functionality you saw.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer. If not, please say what specifically is still to be answered.